# The ellipse $x^2+2y^2=2.$

Tags: calculus

**Question:** The ellipse $x^2+2y^2=2$ is given by $x=a\cos{t}, \quad y=b\sin{t}, \quad t\in[0,2\pi],$ for what values of $a$ and $b$?

a) $(a,b)=(2,1)$

b) $(a,b)=(1,2)$

c) $(a,b)=(1,\sqrt{2})$

d) None of the above.

**Attempt:** Substitute the trig-values for $x$ & $y$ in the elliptic equation:

$$x^2+2y^2=2\Longleftrightarrow a^2\cos^2{t}+2b^2\sin^2{t}=2.$$

Trig identities gives

$$a^2(1-\sin^2{t})+2b^2\sin^2{t}=a^2-a^2\sin^2{t}+2b^2\sin^2{t}=a^2-\sin^2{t}(a^2+2b^2)=2.$$

Solving for $\sin{t}$ gives

$$\sin{t}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2-2}{a^2+2b^2}}=\pm f(a,b).$$

Since $$-1\leq\sin{t}\leq1\Longleftrightarrow -1\leq\pm f(a,b)\leq1.$$

Answer a) gives $f(2,1)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \in[-1,1]$. OK!

Answer b) gives $f(1,2)=\frac{i}{3}\in \mathbb{C}$. Disregard.

Answer c) gives $f(1,\sqrt{2}) = \frac{i\sqrt{5}}{5}\in \mathbb{C}$. Disregard.

So according to me, the correct answer should be a). But correct answer is d). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I did not solve it for $t$.

Comment: have done the calculus again but got this $\sin^2(t)=\frac  {a^2-2} {a²-2b²}$

Comment: In the future, just so you know, $i\sqrt5/5\in\Bbb C$ but $\sqrt3/3\in\Bbb C$ as well

Comment: You equation should be true  for any t and f(2,1) hold only for a certain value of t ...so it's not a solution...$\sin^2(t)=\frac  {a^2-2} {a²-2b²}=1$ holds for $t=\frac \pi 2 $

Comment: Yes I know, since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}.$ Maybe I should write $\notin \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when you wrote $$a^2-a^2\sin^2{t}+2b^2\sin^2{t}=a^2-\sin^2{t}(a^2+2b^2)=2.$$
In fact, 
$$a^2-a^2\sin^2{t}+2b^2\sin^2{t}=a^2-\sin^2{t}(a^2\color{red}{-}2b^2)=2.$$

From here, you can conclude that $a^2=2b^2$ as the right-hand side is not a function of $t$. Consequently, $a^2=2$, and $b^2=1$.

Comment: Still don't understand why I can conclude $a^2=2b^2$.

Comment: @Parseval Suppose $a^2 \neq 2b^2$, and $a^2-2b^2=1$. Then  $a^2-(a^2-2b^2)\sin^2(t) = a^2 - \sin^2(t)$. If you plot the left-hand side as a function of $t$, you will see a sine curve. On the other hand, the right-hand side is a constant. But both sides of an equation must be equal. Therefore, $a^2-2b^2$ must be zero so that the left-hand side becomes a constant or, equivalently, becomes independent of $t$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For Parseval...

\begin{align}
x^2+2y^2 &= 2 \\
a²\cos^2(t) + 2b^2 \sin^2(t) &= 2 \\
\cos^2(t) + \frac {2b^2}{a^2} \sin^2(t) &= \frac 2 {a^2} \\
1-\sin^2(t) + \frac {2b^2}{a^2} \sin^2(t) &= \frac 2 {a^2} \\
(\frac {2b^2}{a^2} -1)\sin^2(t) &= \frac 2 {a^2} -1 \\
( {2b^2}- a^2 )\sin^2(t) &=  2 - {a^2} 
\end{align}

This must be true for any t...You can't solve it for t.
So you need to have:

$$0*\sin^2(t) = 0$$
Therefore, 
\begin{cases}
(2b^2- a^2 )=0 \iff b²= \frac {a^2}{2}=1 \\
2 - {a^2}=0  \iff a=\sqrt 2
\end{cases}

The solution f(2,1) only works for a certain t (=$\pi$ /2) in your formula Parseval...

$( 2- 4 )\sin^2(t)=  2 - 4$

$2\sin^2(t)=  2$

$\sin^2(t)=  1$

It's not true therefore for any t in [0,$2\pi$]....

Answer (score 2):

Write it in the standard form:
$$\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt 2)^2}+\frac{y^2}{1^2}=1$$
Note that the equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
is an ellipse with parametric representation $x=a\cos t$ and $y=b\sin t$.

Comment: Still don't get it. And why is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

In order for $x^2+2y^2=2$ with $x=a\cos(t)$, and $y=b\sin(t)$ we have
$$(a\cos(t))^2+2(b\sin(t))^2=2\iff a^2\cos^2(t)+2b^2\sin^2(t)=2$$
Now we want $a^2=2b^2=2$ since then we can factor out the coefficients and use $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$. Hence, $a=\sqrt 2$ and $b=1$.

Also, just the first error I see in your solution is that we should have: $$a^2-a^2\sin^2(t)+2b^2\sin^2(t)=a^2-\sin^2(t)\left(a^2\color{red}{-}2b^2\right)$$
and not:
$$a^2-a^2\sin^2(t)+2b^2\sin^2(t)=a^2-\sin^2(t)\left(a^2\color{red}{+}2b^2\right)$$

Comment: Why do we want $a^2=2b^2=2$? Can you please show me how you factor the coefficients? And final question, what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: We want the coefficients of $\sin^2(t)$ and $\cos^2(t)$ to be the same, so that we can factor them out and use the identity $\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Putting $t=0$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ into the parametric equation $(x,y) = (a\cos t, b\sin t)$, you'll see that both $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ have to be points on the ellipse. Since these points have to satisfy $x^2+2y^2=2$, plugging in these coordinates tells you that $a^2=2$ and $2b^2=2$.